# Python - output not coming after parsing command line options

Tags: python, input

Below is my code, where I am not getting output... after running script with inputfile and output file...

```
def parseCommandLine(argv=[]):
    inputfile = ''
    outputfile = ''
    FCSNAME = ''

    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(
            argv,
            "hiop", 
            [help,"ifile=","ofile=","pcsfile="])
    except getopt.GetoptError,msg:
        printUsage()
        print "-E-Badly formed command line vishal!"
        print "  ",msg
        sys.exit(1)

    #Processing command line arguments
    for opt, arg in opts:
        opt= opt.lower()

        # Help
        if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            printUsage()
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            inputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            outputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-p", "--pcsname"):
            PCSNAME = arg
        if opt in ("-v"):
            VERBOSE = 1    
    print 'Input file is "', inputfile
    print 'Output file is "', outputfile
    print 'PCS NAME is "', FCSNAME
            # Verbose


    return 0
```

Output: 
./aaa_scr -i list -o vishal

Input file is "
Output file is "
FCS NAME is "

No output is coming.. please help.

Comment: Please help.. your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Exclude the `0`th element from `sys.argv`. i.e. the program name.

```
import getopt
import sys
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(
        sys.argv[1:],
        "i:o:p:",
        ["ifile=","ofile=","pcsfile="])
except getopt.GetoptError,msg:
    print "error : %s" % msg

inputfile, outputfile, FCSNAME = None, None, None
for opt, arg in opts:
    print opt, arg
    if opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
        inputfile = arg
    elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
        outputfile = arg
    elif opt in ("-p", "--pcsname"):
        FCSNAME = arg

print "inputfile %s" % inputfile
print "outputfile %s" % outputfile
print "FCSNAME %s" % FCSNAME
```

Also you have options that require an argument, so you need to handle those using `:` (colon)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

0th element of sys.argv list is the name of program which getopt don't like. So just remove it and then pass argv it to the getopt.

```
import sys 
import getopt

def printUsage():
      print "Usage"

def parseCommandLine(argv=[]):
    argv = argv[1:]
    inputfile = ''
    outputfile = ''
    PCSNAME = ''

    try:
          opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, 'hi:o:p:')
    except getopt.GetoptError,msg:
        printUsage()
        print "-E-Badly formed command line vishal!"
        print "  ",msg
        sys.exit(1)

    #Processing command line arguments
    #print opts
    for opt, arg in opts:
        opt = opt.lower()

        # Help
        if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            printUsage()
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            inputfile = arg 
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            outputfile = arg 
        elif opt in ("-p", "--pcsname"):
            PCSNAME = arg 
        if opt in ("-v"):
            VERBOSE = 1 
    print 'Input file is "', inputfile
    print 'Output file is "', outputfile
    print 'PCS NAME is "', PCSNAME

parseCommandLine(sys.argv)
```